# Passing Arugments to a Rosjava Node

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you pass arguments to a rosjava node?

In the examples,  org.ros.RosRun is used to instantiate the node.  Only a NodeConfiguration is passed to this new node and the NodeConfiguration does not contain the command line arguments.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10418/passing-arugments-to-a-rosjava-node/) by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 508 on 2011-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a todo in NodeConfiguration for that. Please file an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list) and star it if you'd like to track progress on this feature.

In the meantime, I suggest using rosparam.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1